# How to find all the Iptables rules on port 80

Tags: linux, iptables

I was wondering is there a command to list / find all the iptables' rules on port 80 (or any other port)? For example something like this:

```
iptables --list | grep port 80
```

Comment: Your command needs double quotes as the string contains white space: `iptables --list | grep "port 80"`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It was just a general idea on syntax. No quotes or any other 'variations' of this command show the iptables rules on port 80.

Comment: That means that there are no rules for port 80. Run the command without `grep` and you'll see all of the rules.

Comment: Thanks. There are many iptbales' rules on port 80, but the command I "thought of" (iptables --list | grep port 80) either with or without quotes, grep and so on simply does not work. I do not need all the rules, I need only those applied to port 80.

Comment: Instead of using "port 80" use "http" - It appears that iptables uses the mappings in /etc/services  for known ports.   Alternatively you can use the -n switch to disable lookups.  Also, grep ":80"  (not port 80)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `iptables --list` defaults to the `FILTER` table. There may be other rules in other tables, so use `-t NAT` etc. for the rest.

Comment: I apologize for the error on my part. Your `grep` string should be `grep "ports 80" or `grep "dports 80". The string that will appear is `dports 80` so either of those `grep` strings will return the output that you want.

Comment: Hey davidgo your suggestion iptables --list | grep ":80" returned zero results, even though there are many rules on port 80.

Answer (score 4):

```
 iptables --list|grep "spt:\|dpt:\|dports\|sports"
```

spt: and dpt       cover individual port rules

sports and dports  cover multiport command

Now all rules that mention ports should be listed.

```
 iptables --list|grep "spt:\|dpt:\|dports\|sports"|grep http
```

Once you do this you realize that iptables uses the port name, so you have to grep for http instead of 80.

If you want to see actual port numbers you will to do this:

```
 iptables-save|grep "spt:\|dpt:\|dports\|sports"
```

The output will be significantly different so this may or may not work for you.

```
 iptables-save|grep "spt:\|dpt:\|dports\|sports"|grep 80
```

Comment: Wow! Excellent! Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed!

Comment: You can just use "-n" in the iptables command to see actual port numbers.